# How to count related rows including subcategories?

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate, postgresql-12

I've got a few tables in a Postgres 12.3 database.

The first one is named `category`:

```
id|template_id|name           |entry_count|is_base_template|can_rename|can_delete|section|userId|parentCategoryId|
--|-----------|---------------|-----------|----------------|----------|----------|-------|------|----------------|
 1|           |Notes          |          0|true            |true      |true      |A      |      |                |
 2|           |ToDo           |          0|true            |true      |true      |A      |      |                |
 3|          1|Notes          |          0|false           |true      |true      |A      |     1|                |
 4|          2|ToDo           |          0|false           |true      |true      |A      |     1|                |
 5|           |Must Do        |          0|false           |          |          |A      |      |               4|
 6|           |Important notes|          0|false           |          |          |A      |      |               3|
```

The second table is called `entry` - which has no bearing on the question at hand.

And there is the link table `category_entries_entry`:

```
categoryId|entryId|
----------|-------|
         4|      1|
         5|      5|
         5|      6|
         4|      7|
         3|      8|
         6|      9|
```

A category can possess children, if `parentCategoryId` is not NULL then we're dealing with a child. For instance, the category with `id = 5` is a subcategory of `id = 4`. Children can't have their own children, so only one level of nesting.

I need to count the number of entries for each category *including* subcategories.

This request does what I need, mostly. But it does not take into account the user:

```
SELECT COALESCE(c."parentCategoryId" , c.id) as cat_id , COUNT(*) as entries_in_cat
FROM category c JOIN
     category_entries_entry r
     ON c.id = r."categoryId" 
WHERE c.is_base_template = false
GROUP BY cat_id;
```

Returns:

```
cat_id|entries_in_cat|
------|--------------|
     4|             4|
     3|             2|
```

The `category` table has also `userId` and the count should only be executed for a given user. Notably, only root categories have entries for `userId`.

And I want to list subcategories with their counts *additionally*. So the **desired output** with `userId = 1` for the given sample is:

```
cat_id|entries_in_cat|
------|--------------|
     5|             2|
     4|             4|
     6|             1|
     3|             2|
```

Here's a break down:

1) Category number 6 is a subcategory of the 3rd category it has 1 entry, so the result is correct.

2) Category number 3 is a category (that's to say, it does not have a parent), it contains 1 entry and another one should come from the 6th subcategory, that's 2 in total. Your script returns 1 which is wrong.

3) Category number 5 is a subcategory of the 4th category, it contains 2 entries. Your script returns also 2 which is right.

4) category number 4 is a category, it has 2 entries of its own and another two come from the 5th subcategory, that's 4 in total. Your script returns 2 which is wrong. It should return 4.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: In the sample data the `userId` = `1` is specified for categories `3` and `4`. If we choose this user, should the subcategories `5` and `6` be also included? They don't have the same user.

Comment: @TheImpaler yeah because the subcategories 5 and 6 belong to the same user. It's evident from their `parentCategoryId`. Their corresponsing parent category ids are 4 and 3, so yeah they belong to the same user.

Comment: To focus the question, I took the liberty to copyedit extensively. Please fix if I got anything wrong.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I've just checked it, yeah everything looks great, now it's become more clear! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the job for a *single* level of nesting:

To list only root categories, counts include subcategories:

```
WITH root AS (
   SELECT id AS cat_id, id AS sub_id
   FROM   category
   WHERE  is_base_template = false
   AND    "userId" = 1
   )
SELECT c.cat_id, count(*)::int AS entries_in_cat
FROM  (
   TABLE root
   UNION ALL
   SELECT r.cat_id, c.id
   FROM   root     r
   JOIN   category c ON c."parentCategoryId" = r.cat_id
   ) c
JOIN   category_entries_entry e ON e."categoryId" = c.sub_id
GROUP  BY c.cat_id;
```

The point is to join on `sub_id`, but group by `cat_id`.

To list root categories like above, and subcategories *additionally*:

```
WITH root AS (
   SELECT id AS cat_id, id AS sub_id
   FROM   category
   WHERE  is_base_template = false
   AND    "userId" = 1
   )
, ct AS (
   SELECT c.cat_id, c.sub_id, count(*)::int AS ct
   FROM  (
      TABLE root
      UNION ALL
      SELECT r.cat_id, c.id AS sub_id
      FROM   root     r
      JOIN   category c ON c."parentCategoryId" = r.cat_id
      ) c
   JOIN   category_entries_entry e ON e."categoryId" = c.sub_id
   GROUP  BY c.cat_id, c.sub_id
   )
SELECT cat_id, sum(ct)::int AS entries_in_cat
FROM   ct
GROUP  BY 1

UNION ALL
SELECT sub_id, ct
FROM   ct
WHERE  cat_id <> sub_id;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=000aaa56c2f0aa97650dee3baad92ef2)*

For an arbitrary number of nesting levels, use a recursive CTE. Example:

- [How to link rows in a many-to-many relationship where types have parents, grandparents etc](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/209879/3684)

About the optional short syntax `TABLE parent`:

- [Is there a shortcut for SELECT * FROM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30275979/is-there-a-shortcut-for-select-from/30276023#30276023)

Comment: Sorry for the delay with the reply, I was half dead this Friday...the script does what I need but is it possible to add counts for subcategories (like in the EDIT I made in the question)? If not , then I will have to count them with  a separate query.

Comment: @Albert: I added another solution to list subcategories additionally.

Comment: Thank you ever so much!

Answer (score 1):

Since the filtering applies to the parent categories only you'll need to apply it there first: then you can get the subcategories. Once you have the parent categories and the subcategories, you can join them to the entries and count them.

In sum, the query should look like:

```
with
c as (
  SELECT id
  FROM category
  WHERE userId = 1 AND is_base_template = false
),
s as (
  SELECT d.id
  FROM c
  JOIN category d on d.parentCategoryId = c.id
)
SELECT u.id, count(*) as entries_in_cat
FROM (select id from c union select id from s) u
JOIN category_entries_entry r ON u.id = r."categoryId" 
GROUP BY u.id
```

Comment: Thank you. It throws an error at the moment, it says: `ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "c"`.

Comment: @Albert Fixed... See https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/koMxJCwn8iovXZXHy5oNQf/0

Comment: Hmm it works but still does not return what I need =( First of all, it's great if it returns counts for subcategories, BUT and this is important, the counts for categories should also include the numbers for subcategories. For example, the fourth category contains two its own entries but another two come from its subcategories, so the total should be four, not 2. Is it achievable? I would greatly appreciate if you would modify the script so that it would work this way. Thank you.

Comment: @Albert Please add the example to DBFiddle so I can run it and test it. Also please provide the exact expected result.

Comment: I extremely appologise for the delay, I was extremely exhausted this Friday...now returning to all this. I've edited my question, could you please take a look. I'm not very good with fiddle, but I hope I was clear enough in that edit I made.